# Update script to replace number for each host then transfer the new file to the set of servers

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, edit

Basically what I am looking to do is setup an update server. I have multiple raspberry pi's that need to be updated, sshing into them takes a lot of time. Once I have a new script that needs to be pushed out to each raspberry pi, one number in the new script needs to be changed according to the raspberry pi. Once that is changed for the raspberry pi then the script needs to be transferred to that pi via scp preferably. Then the update script will continue on to the next pi and change the new script accordingly.

I am not quite sure how I should set this up.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bare bones:

```
for x in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
    host=$(printf "myhost%02d" $x)
    # also use this number to edit the script etc etc.
    scp MYSCRIPT $host:
done
```

Having said that, if all the scripts differ is some single number, I'd strongly recommend making the script data-driven (i.e. hostname-driven) so you maintain same copy of the script across all machines:

```
# my script running on series of machines named machineNNN
machnum=$(hostname | sed 's/^machine//')
# now use $machnum in your script.
```